# Ultra simple method of deleting last char from String failing

Tags: java

I'm simply trying to delete the last char in a String, I know this is a simple task and has been done any times BUT for some reason it doesn't work.

Example method

```
public String removeLastChar(String stringToRemoveCharFrom)
{
    if(stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() > 0)
    {
        return stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length());
    }
    else{
        return stringToRemoveCharFrom;
    }
}
```

Now, when I output the string sometimes I get an empty char at the end, when I call this function it runs the correct way BUT the string stays the same.

Debugger shows:
\b in some of the outputs, what is this? And how do I avoid it?

Any ideas?

---

I replaced the end with -1 like in the answers but it still fails to delete:

```
return stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() - 1);
```

It seems for some reason JAVA is entering weird characters that cannot be deleted. such as \b.

If I do the following at the start:

```
stringToRemoveCharFrom = stringToRemoveCharFrom.replaceAll("\b", "");
```

it works. But I'm wondering what this char is?

Comment: Replace stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() with stringToRemoveCharFrom.length()-1

Comment: Off by one errors... a programmer's nightmare

Comment: ...please calm, re-complie & feedback :-)

Comment: of course `substring(...)` doesn't change the orginal string..it `return`s *a new* string (of length`= to - from`)

Comment: "\b" is the escape for the "backspace character"..

Comment: How do you make sure  the string stays the same??? Did you try to compare original string and result and show us the result? Does your string has some control characters?

Comment: Please don't incorporate answers in to your question code! It makes it confusing for future readers because they do not know what the answers are referring to. Instead, you can use an `<hr>` to create a separator if you want to make additions.

Answer (score 0):

`stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length())`

will return the entire String. What you should be doing is:

`stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() - 1)`

This is because `substring(int start, int end)` returns a substring starting at "start", and ending at the index 1 before "end". The starting index is inclusive, the end is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to subtract one from the length:

```
public String removeLastChar(String stringToRemoveCharFrom)
{
    if(stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() > 0)
    {
        return stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring
               (0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() - 1);
    }
    else{
        return stringToRemoveCharFrom;
    }
}
```

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns Seems to work fine. Could you please further edit your question and show a full example of code that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length());
```

Is a copy of the string, if you want to strip the last character, use:

```
stringToRemoveCharFrom.substring(0, stringToRemoveCharFrom.length() - 1);
```